# C- how to make a variable to be big end. by default?

Tags: c, endianness

I want my program to use big end by default (now it is little).
That means,everytime I declare an uint_32/int,the value which be transformed to it will be on big end order.
Is that possible? (Without calling each time to ntohl()).

I have researched on google and s.o for 3 days and haven't got any anawer 
I will strongly appreciate any help!

edit:
I have server and client.
The client works with big endian,and the server is little endian.
Now,i am sending to the server md5 value for a byte array,ntohl()ing it on the server and get the valid md5 value.

In the server,when I call the md5.c function (which is dll,by the way),I am getting a different value.
This value is not even similair on any way to the recived value.
I assume it happens because of the endiannes.
The byte array I send to the function is not changing because those are single bytes,which are not seensetive the endianess,but the vars I declare on the function,and with them I manipulate my byte arr,can make a problem.

That is the reason big endian is so important to me.

Comment: Please explain why big endian is so important to you. So [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53144059/edit) your question to improve it

Comment: Why cannot you use `ntohl`? And why do you assume that the endianness is the problem? Have you not checked this to confirm?

Answer (score 4):

> I want my program to use big end by default

You cannot. The [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is a *fixed* property of the target processor (of your C compiler) and related to its [instruction set architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture).

You might in principle (but with C, that is really not worth the trouble) use a C compiler for some virtual machine (like [WebAssembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly), or [MMIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMIX)) of the appropriate endianness, or even define a bytecode VM for a machine of desired endianness.

A variant of that might be to [cross-compile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) for some *other* instruction set architecture (e.g. MIPS, ARM, etc...) and use some [emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator) to run the executable (and the necessary OS).

Regarding your edit, you could consider sending on the network the `md5sum` in *alphanumerical* form (e.g. like the output of the `md5sum` command).

Comment: Actually I have server on c# which uses the md5.c (dll) and a c client. I am sending my md5 value to the server,ntoh()ing it but when I call the md5 value with the same input,it retruns a weird md5 value. I thought it happens because the vars on the md5.dll are on little end,so when I manipulate my input with those values,it returns me the different value.

Comment: That should go into the question, and that does not explain why you need big endianness

Comment: Looks like @דוראיטח has a binary compiled library for a concrete arch and want to reuse it elsewhere ¿?

Answer (score 2):

You can compile the program for different processors, some of which use big endian instead of little endian, or you can control how your code will be compiled in that aspect. For example, for MIPS: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/MIPS-Options.html

Answer (score 1):

Endianness is purely about how a processor performs multi-byte arithmetic. The only time a programmer need to be aware is when serializing or addressing parts of an integer.

So unless you can change how a processor performs arithmetic on multi-byte words (ARM allows you to change endianness) you are stuck with how the processor works.